# Image options to customize the visibility of tabs

Tags: jodit

**Expected behaviour:** With respect to my use case, when the user clicks on image button, I must allow the user to only upload the image and hence I have to hide the URL tab.

**Actual behaviour:**   Currently there is no such option to hide the URL and to display only upload tab.